# Git won't allow me to switch branches

Tags: git

$git branch 
**stable**
development

I have properties file which has password for Database connection, now I had to change the properties file (say xyz.properties) for password. So that i can use on local server.
and added this file path into .gitignore and 
$git update-index --assume-unchanged xyz.properties

$git status
On branch stable
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/stable'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Now i wanted to change ...branch to development
$git checkout development

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .gitignore
    x/y/z/xyz.properties

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

**Now**
 I want to change branch to development and make branch and work on them.

So how can i achieve this task...please help me out.
Thanks in Advance

**Edit**
when i tried 
$git stash
No local changes to save

Note: I need to use local server from every branch , which required my xyz.properties files to be modified because my local db has different password then repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is to modify the xyz.properties file as per your environment need, so if you try to put it into .gitignore file, it will not work, because xyz.properties is tracked file and synced with repository.so now there is two things can be done.

1> untrack the xyz.properties file and put them into .gitignore, but it will not sync with repository, and you cannot share a basic properties file which is beneficial for other programmers who are using same project and requires the repository and properties file.

2> make a xyz.properties.example in repo that will be shared and synced by repo and will be available to everyone who are using the same project.
   Now put xyz.propertes into .gitignore , who ever is using will create local file and copy the contents from xyz.properties.example , and obviously that file will remain untracked and ignored.

Hence you can achieve your task...better way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure stash it and switch another branch

```
git stash
git checkout development
```

Now you can work at branch development

when you checkout back, you need restore your workplace and delete stash

```
git checkout last_branch
git stash pop
```

Notice: you can check out your stash status by

```
git stash list
```

if it returns nothing. Your workplace is clean. Now you can work at last_branch.

Comment: when I am doing $git stash

It is showing: No local changes to save

Comment: If no local changes to save, you just execute `git checkout development` will be fine. If you are not sure, you can execute `git status` to check out  your workplace current status.

Comment: I found the issue , it was due to properties file were tracked, so there is two either you have to untrack those file, but this policy is not good. I will answer with the right policy...thank you for your help.